# JS function: why this won't alert my greeting?

Tags: javascript

I am curious why this won't alert my greeting. The code:

```
function myNameWelcome(userName, thought) {
  var greeting = "Welcome pardner, so your're name is " + userName + ". " + thought;
  return greeting;
}

myNameWelcome("Peter", "Shine on you crazy diamond.");

alert(greeting);
```

Comment: `alert(myNameWelcome(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`greeting` is out of scope. It was defined inside the function so it's not available at the scope you're calling `alert(greeting);`. Fixing this is easy:

```
var greeting;
function myNameWelcome(userName, thought) {
  greeting = "Welcome pardner, so your're name is " + userName + ". " + thought;
}

myNameWelcome("Peter", "Shine on you crazy diamond.");

alert(greeting);
```

or even better:

```
function myNameWelcome(userName, thought) {
  return "Welcome pardner, so your're name is " + userName + ". " + thought;
}

var greeting = myNameWelcome("Peter", "Shine on you crazy diamond.");

alert(greeting);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return value isn't being assigned to anything outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Because `greeting` is a *local variable* only accessible *within* `myNameWelcome`. It does not exist outside of the function.

See [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) to learn more about variable scope.